# How to Access Asp hidden field in External js File

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I know that I can't use **<%= hdnObjectID.ClientID %>** in an external js file because these server side expressions don't evaluate in an external js file.

And, I have to create a function in my aspx page to get the value from that hidden field.

But, how can I create this function?

I want to store the drop down value in a hidden field and I will use these hidden fields on server side. But, the problem is that I have an external .JS file there on every drop down change I want to store into a hidden field.

**I am not sure is this a good Approach or not**

.js File

```
  $('#ddlCountry').change(function (e) {

        var CountryCode = parseInt(document.getElementById('hdnCountry').value);
        CountryCode.val(this.value);

        var CountryName = parseInt(document.getElementById('hdnCountrytext').value);
        CountryName.val($("[id$='ddlCountry'] option:selected").text());

        BindCompanies();

    });
```

Aspx:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCountry" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCompany" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

.Cs

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryCode", hdnCountry.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryName", hdnCountrytext.Value);
```

[image: Can i use Something Like this ?]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to declare the variables on aspx file just before you call the javascript file

```
var hdnObjectIDClientId = <%=hdnObjectID.ClientID%>;
// and now include your javascript and use the variable hdnObjectIDClientId
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourjavascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: You mean on top of my page my all hidden field should be there right ?

Comment: i have added one image Some thing like this right ?

Comment: @cdd on top of your page, just before the js call - there is a good place to put it